# Cannot change or remove a file as root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, wordpress, vulnerability

This is driving me nuts... There's a lot of info over the place and I've spent quite some hours already without any success. A customer of mine haves a website compromised with some japanese SEO spam (seems to be a known threat for wordpress websites: https://labs.sucuri.net/signatures/sitecheck/spam-seo/?japanese.0)

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and the latest WordPress (all the plugins and core updated, restored core files from a fresh download as well, with sucuri, iThemes Security and Wordfence installed)

Unfortunately rolling back to a previous safe-state is not possible being that there are many transactions that happened since then, and we're uncertain about when the malware got introduced.
Now everything seems to be cleaned up, except one single thing: the index.php file.
There's NO WAY to remove / edit / do anything with this file, even by using the root user.

```
[root@site /home/xxxx.com/public_html] # ls -l index.php
-r--r--r--  1 www www  6982 Apr 13  2022 index.php

[root@site /home/xxxx.com/public_html] # lsattr index.php
--------------e----- ./index.php

[root@site /home/xxxx.com/public_html] # chmod 755 index.php
[root@site /home/xxxx.com/public_html] # ls -l index.php
-r--r--r--  1 www www  6982 Apr 13  2022 index.php

[root@site /home/xxxx.com/public_html] # rm -f index.php
[root@site /home/xxxx.com/public_html] # ls -l index.php
-r--r--r--  1 www www  6982 Apr 13  2022 index.php
```

So no matter what I do, the file remains untouched. Already verified, it's not a symlink (nor a hardlink), and the content is always the same:

```
<?php
$a='fgss332';$O00OO0=urldecode("%6E1%7A%62%2F%6D%615%5C%76%740%6928%2D%70%78%75%71%79%2A6%6C%72%6B%64%679%5F%65%68%63%73%77%6F4%2B%6637%6A");
....
// there's more crap to inject a scamming website here
?>
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

Does anybody know what can possibly be happening here? Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you reinstalled Linux? If not then there may be modifications to the standard commands or a rootkit protecting that file. The only mechanism I am aware of which could protect the file without such modifications would be a read-only bind mount of that file upon itself: `findmnt index.php` But that should generate an error message at least. What is the output of `type ls lsattr chmod rm` (assuming bash)?

Comment: Yeah this sounds like you want to move the innocent data to a new virtual machine or container and just scrap the old thing altogether.

Comment: @HaukeLaging thanks for your input! `findmnt index.php` has no output. `type ls lsattr chmod rm` returns:

`ls is aliased to "ls -A --color=auto'
lsattr is hashed (/usr/bin/lsattr)
chmod is hashed (/usr/bin/chmod)
rm is aliased to "rm -i'

Comment: Is the inode of the file changing after you delete it? (`ls -i index.php`).  If so, the file isn't delete-proof- something else is immediately replacing it.

Comment: @DopeGhoti no the inode is not changing.. nothing replacing it I believe, checked crontabs as well, nothing suspicious over there

Comment: When you run `rm -rf <file>`, and the file does not exist, the `rm` command does not return an error. Therefore, does the file `index.php` actually exist, or does it have trailing or other embedded non-printing chars? Are you using tab completion which would mask such a thing? Just try `rm index.php` and see what is returned.

Comment: Another possibility is that it is hard linked to another file and some process is creating that link which will not change the inode number. So, what is the output of `stat -c "%h" index.php`?